# Apache Mahout Maven Build Failure MRLegacy

Tags: apache, maven, hadoop, mahout

Facing this error while configuring Apache Mahout.
I am using the following:
Java version "1.8.0_31"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_31-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.31-b07, mixed mode)

Maven Version:
Apache Maven 3.0.5 (r01de14724cdef164cd33c7c8c2fe155faf9602da; 2013-02-19 19:21:28+0530)
Java version: 1.8.0_31, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_31/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "2.6.32-504.3.3.el6.x86_64", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"

Here is the error I am facing:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:2.4:single (job) on project mahout-mrlegacy: Failed to create assembly: Error creating assembly archive job: error in opening zip file -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:2.4:single (job) on project mahout-mrlegacy: Failed to create assembly: Error creating assembly archive job: error in opening zip file
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:217)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Failed to create assembly: Error creating assembly archive job: error in opening zip file
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.assembly.mojos.AbstractAssemblyMojo.execute(AbstractAssemblyMojo.java:495)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
        ... 19 more
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.assembly.archive.ArchiveCreationException: Error creating assembly archive job: error in opening zip file
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.assembly.archive.DefaultAssemblyArchiver.createArchive(DefaultAssemblyArchiver.java:190)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.assembly.mojos.AbstractAssemblyMojo.execute(AbstractAssemblyMojo.java:436)
        ... 21 more
Caused by: org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.ArchiverException: error in opening zip file
        at org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.AbstractArchiver$1.hasNext(AbstractArchiver.java:472)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.assembly.filter.ComponentsXmlArchiverFileFilter.finalizeArchiveCreation(ComponentsXmlArchiverFileFilter.java:166)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.AbstractArchiver.runArchiveFinalizers(AbstractArchiver.java:884)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.AbstractArchiver.createArchive(AbstractArchiver.java:908)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.assembly.archive.archiver.AssemblyProxyArchiver.createArchive(AssemblyProxyArchiver.java:512)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.assembly.archive.DefaultAssemblyArchiver.createArchive(DefaultAssemblyArchiver.java:186)
        ... 22 more
Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:220)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:150)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:164)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.components.io.resources.PlexusIoZipFileResourceCollection.getEntries(PlexusIoZipFileResourceCollection.java:53)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.components.io.resources.AbstractPlexusIoArchiveResourceCollection.getResources(AbstractPlexusIoArchiveResourceCollection.java:76)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.components.io.resources.proxy.PlexusIoProxyResourceCollection.getResources(PlexusIoProxyResourceCollection.java:89)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.AbstractArchiver$1.hasNext(AbstractArchiver.java:468)
        ... 27 more
[ERROR]
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
[ERROR]
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :mahout-mrlegacy
```

Any help will be deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution the problem:
I updated the version of Apache Maven which I was using to "**Apache Maven 3.2.5"** and also had to remove to "**.m2**" directory.

After than ran "*mvn -DskipTests clean install*" and things got resolved.
Hope this helps anyone who gets stuck on the same issue.